# How to load my app and youtube in one window in electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to load my app and youtube in one window. As result it should display right and left block. The app in right block and youtube in left and customize titleBars for both. Exptected behaviour is like to open dev tools and manage two windows [screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TIVT.png). How to implement this ?
I've tried BrowserView but it seems there is no way to make what i want with it

Comment: you can set `iframe`s of each domain

Comment: Youtube doesn't allow to use iframe

Comment: well managing 2 windows of different origin is sort of against what cors is about